# C++ Pointer Issues when passing to a function

Tags: c++, pointers

**Solution Below** For almost a year, I thought I completely understood pointers, and now it's failing. I will post the entire file if it is even needed.

```
// Test Structure and Function
struct You {
    int x;
    int y;
    string str;
};

bool Show(You* showValue);


// Should (delete) in whatever way possible and update its address to the     "You* update" you sent
void Update(You* update, int n) {

    // Create a new "You"
    You* youTwo = new You();
    youTwo->x = 55;
    youTwo->y = 43;
    youTwo->str = "Twin";

    // Update?
    update = youTwo;

    return; 
};




bool Show(You* showValue) {
    cout << "Show:" << endl;
    cout << showValue->x << '\t';
    cout << showValue->y << '\t';
    cout << showValue->str << '\t'; 
    cout << endl << endl;
};



int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // Original You
    You* currentYou = new You();
    currentYou->x = 1;
    currentYou->y = 2;
    currentYou->str = "You";

    // Update the current you to a new you
    Show(currentYou);   // works
    Update(currentYou, 5);  // no compile errors
    Show(currentYou); // shows initial values instead of the updated

    return 0;
};
```

The `Update` function is where the issue is. My intentions is to delete (or get rid) of the original. Replacing it with a `new You()` and be done with it.

Comment: Well, congrats to solving the problem. Meanwhile, if you keep the original problematic code there and provide the solution separately, it will be more useful to other readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



// Test Structure and Function
    struct You {
    int x;
    int y;
    string str;
};


bool Show(You* showValue);



// Should (delete) in whatever way possible and update its address to the "You* update" you sent
void Update(You*& update, int n) {

// Clean Up
delete update;

// Create a new "You"
You* youTwo = new You();
youTwo->x = 55;
youTwo->y = 43;
youTwo->str = "Twin";

// Update address
update = youTwo;

return; 
};




bool Show(You* showValue) {
cout << "Show:" << endl;
cout << showValue->x << '\t';
cout << showValue->y << '\t';
cout << showValue->str << '\t'; 
cout << endl << endl;
};



int main(int argc, char** argv) {

// Original You
You* currentYou = new You();
currentYou->x = 1;
currentYou->y = 2;
currentYou->str = "You";

// Update the current you to a new you
Show(currentYou);
Update(currentYou, 5); 
Show(currentYou); 

delete currentYou;
return 0;
};
```

The memory leak is fixed (the `delete`'s were added,) and the pointer is a pointer-ref now. Works perfect.

Comment: What if there's another reference to the old `update` when calling `Update`? You invalidate it completely, without anybody knowing

Answer (score 3):

You pass the pointer to `You` by value to `void Update(You*,int)`. Thus `update = youTwo;` this has no effect on `currentYou`.

Change `Update` to `void Update(You*& update, in n) { //...` and read up on references.

Btw, you have a memory leak. You update the pointer, but you never deallocate the old `currentYou` nor the new `currentYou`. You should use "smart pointers" (explicitly `shared_ptr<You>`) to clean up everything behind you, without having to call `delete` every time yourself.

Comment: thanks, the memory leak I actually left, I was trying to rule that out of the issue. I will try your advise.

Comment: @EvanCarslake, you have to `delete update;` before you assign `youTwo` so that you delete the previous `You`. Other than that it should be fine (after formatting)